# Installing ubuntu on rack server (HP Proliant)

Tags: linux

I have recently been given a HP Proliant DL385 server, which came with no HDDs. So I bought a new HDD and put it in. All great so far.

My problem comes with I want to install ubuntu on it. The other problem is, there is no optical cd-rom drive/floppy drive.

How would I go about doing this without inserting a ubuntu install disk? Can I do it through some command line interface/network install?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ubuntu can be installed over network](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation#Server%20and%20network%20installations)
[or from a USB stick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

Comment: Thanks I'll look at both options

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/Netboot) might be helpful. Also, if network install is not an option, maybe you can put the hdd into another machine and install the system there? If you have luck, the it will work when you move the HDD back to the server.